# How to use the list.toArray() method in Java for a two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

I created a list of int arrays, and I want to return it as a 2D array.

```
List<int[]> ans = new ArrayList<>();
int[][] toReturn = new int[ans.size()][];
return ans.toArray(toReturn);
```

How does this code work? What is the difference between `list.toArray()` and `list.toArray(T[] a)`?

Comment: Did you try the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray--)?

Comment: A `List<List<Integer>>` would work too, by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toArray` creates a brand new array while `toArray(T[] arr)` tries to put all elements of the list into the provided `arr` array.

Comment: And `toArray()` returns an `Object` array instead of `T[]`.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to use foreach loop for you list and a normal loop for the array.

```
public int[][] toArray(ArrayList<> inputList){
int[][] toReturn = new int[inputList.size()][];
int i =0;
for(int[] arrayOfInts : inputList){
  for(int j=0;j<arrayOfInts.length;j++){
  toReturn[i][j]=arrayOfInts [j] ;
  }
i++;
}
return toReturn  ;
}
```